# Error while using CHECK clause in SQL (MS access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using MS Access. While I was creating a table:

```
CREATE TABLE student(
    StudentID INT NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Age INT NOT NULL,
    GENDER VARCHAR(9),
    PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    check(Age >= 17)
    );
```

with this code, it is showing error message with

> Syntax error in field definition

Can anyone please help me with that? Thanks.

Comment: Storing age is usually a bad plan to begin with - because you *know* that within a year, that data will be incorrect. DOB, on the other hand, doesn't tend to change and age can easily be *derived* from it.

Comment: Start with identifying the problem line. Remove one row at the time and see when the problem disappears. Divide and qonquer.

Comment: "PRIMARY KEY(ID),", you have no ID column, but a StudentID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Access, you have to introduce your PK and CHECK constraints in [`CONSTRAINT` clauses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/constraint-clause-microsoft-access-sql). Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE student(
    StudentID INT NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Age INT NOT NULL,
    GENDER VARCHAR(9),
    CONSTRAINT PK_student PRIMARY KEY(StudentID),
    CONSTRAINT CK_student_age check(Age >= 17)
    );
```

(Also fixed column name in PK, thanks to jarlh)

Comment: this is also showing error with error message "Syntax error in CONSTRAINT clause"

Comment: You'll have to execute this over an OLEDB connection or turn on SQL Server compatible syntax for it to work.